# preg_match not defined in php4 in openwrt?

Tags: php, openwrt

I have installed the packages PHP4 and PHP4-CGI in openwrt through command line (opkg install)

when I tried this simple code by putting this in the openwrt www folder,

```
<?php
$subject = "abcdef";
$pattern = '/^def/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

I got this error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function: preg_match() in /www/phptest.php on line 4

but php manual says preg_match() is defined in php4 also.. What might be the reason for this error? Is there any other PHP module that is to be installed?
 Or is there any alternate method for preg_match?

Comment: As with any other function that resides in an extension, in PHP4 and PHP5, it will only be defined if PHP was built with the extension (PCRE in this case) or the extension was dynamically loaded. Even if you are running a version where it should be "bundled by default", it can still be disabled. Check your configure line (visible with `phpinfo()`).

Comment: I checked phpinfo();.. I contains a row named configure command which contains some informations .I am listing some of them which contains disabled in it     '--disable-nls''--disable-static'      '--disable-rpath' '--disable-debug'  '--disable-overload' '--disable-short-tags' '--disable-ctype' '--disable-dom'  '--disable-mbstring' '--disable-mbregex'  '--disable-tokenizer' '--disable-gd-jis-conv' '--disable-cli' '--disable-fastcgi'

Comment: @DaveRandom  your comment says everything,, I got a solution. Can I post the answer? or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the function preg_match() (PCRE) into ereg, It works for php4 in openwrt.